# SQL: self join using each rows only once

Tags: sql, join, self-join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [combinations (not permutations) from cross join in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112513/combinations-not-permutations-from-cross-join-in-sql)

I've currently got a table with the following records:

```
A1
A2
A3
B1
B2
C1
C2
```

Where the same letter denotes some criteria in common (e.g. a common value for the column 'letter').  I do a self join on the criteria as follows:

```
SELECT mytable.*, self.* FROM mytable INNER JOIN mytable AS self 
   ON (mytable.letter = self.letter and mytable.number != self.number);
```

This join gives something like the following:

```
A1 A2
A2 A1
A1 A3
A3 A1
A2 A3
A3 A2
B1 B2
B2 B1
C1 C2
C2 C1
```

However, I only want to include each pair once (a combination instead of a permutation).
How would I get the following:

```
A1 A2
A1 A3
A2 A3
B1 B2
C1 C2
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Changing the JOIN condition slightly will achieve what you want..

Instead of:

```
ON (mytable.letter = self.letter and mytable.number != self.number)
```

use

```
ON (mytable.letter = self.letter and mytable.number > self.number)
```

This will only include combinations where `self.number` is greater than `mytable.number` which in effect restricts the results to one valid ordering of each combination...