# Duplicate pairs in SQL cross join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates, cross-join

I know there are a lot of similar questions to this out there on SO, and I looked at some of them, namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112513/combinations-not-permutations-from-cross-join-in-sql), but its not enough to solve my problem

I have a table `proposals` that looks something like this:

```
proposalNum | PI        | department | investigator | investigatorDepartment|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
FP00003521  | Bush,Raj  | GIS        | Amm,Anna     | CIS                   |
FP00003521  | Bush,Raj  | GIS        | Milton,Ross  | CIS                   |
FP00003521  | Bush,Raj  | GIS        | Landis, Amy  | SEB                   |
FP00069606  | Mill, Ash | DIA        | Keller, Bill | FAA                   |
```

and I basically want to look at the `investigator` field and create:

```
Amm,Anna     | Milton, Ross 
Amm,Anna     | Landis, Amy
Milton,Ross  | Landis, Amy
```

for all of the investigators that have `CIS`, and for a given `proposalNum`(in this case, `FP00003521`)

(Here is the **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7f83/4)**)

I did this:

```
SELECT p1.investigator,p2.investigator
FROM proposals AS p1
CROSS JOIN proposals AS p2 
WHERE p1.investigatorDepartment='CIS' 
AND p1.investigator!=p2.investigator
AND p1.proposalNum=p2.proposalNum
```

and got:

```
Milton,Ross  | Amm,Anna 
Amm,Anna     | Milton,Ross
Amm,Anna     | Landis, Amy
Milton,Ross  | Landis,Amy
```

But there's a repeat there...

Following the logic on the linked post, I also tried:

```
SELECT p1.investigator,p2.investigator
FROM proposals AS p1
CROSS JOIN proposals AS p2 
ON p1.investigator < p2.investigator
WHERE p1.investigatorDepartment='CIS' 
AND p1.investigator!=p2.investigator
AND p1.proposalNum=p2.proposalNum
```

and I got this:

```
Amm,Anna     | Milton,Ross
Amm,Anna     | Landis, Amy
```

The problem is when I add the `ON p1.investigator < p2.investigator` condition, it also won't add `Milton,Ross` and `Landis, Amy` since `M > L`

How would I re-write my query to solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!!

Comment: `p1.investigatorDepartment='CIS'` -> `Landis, Amy`'s dept is SEB. That's why it does not come up. You should revise your rule, or change `p1.investigatorDepartment='CIS'` to `(p1.investigatorDepartment='CIS' OR p2.investigatorDepartment='CIS')`

Comment: @Sebas thanks... but if the reason that `Landis,Amy` doesn't come up is because of the `='CIS'` condition, why does it show up in the first one? And I tried the `OR` condition but I got even more repeats.

Comment: Landis,Amy shows up in the first one, but on the right side, and because Amm,Anna is included. You want it on the left side.

Comment: @Sebas Um.... why would I want it on the left side?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. Your rule is crooked. You should have p1 AND p2 limited by CIS otherwise the constraint of unicity you wish to implement in order to filter out duplicate should use that column as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join those `p2's` that are CIS differently to those that aren't. One way is as follows.

```
select
  p1.investigator,
  p2.investigator
from
  proposals AS p1
    cross join
  proposals AS p2 
where
  p1.investigatorDepartment = 'CIS' and ((
      p2.investigatorDepartment = 'CIS' and 
      p1.investigator < p2.investigator
  ) or (
      p2.investigatorDepartment != 'CIS' or
      p2.investigatorDepartment is null
  )) and
  p1.proposalNum = p2.proposalNum;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b7f83/10)